# Single shortcut to save-compile-execute C++ program in Emacs?

Tags: c++, windows, emacs, g++, user-input

I have been trying to figure out a way to efficiently save a program, compile it and then run it in emacs. I have succeeded only partially in it.

I use smart-compile.el to make the job easier ( http://emacswiki.org/emacs/smart-compile.el ).
In that I have edited the C++ relevant portion to the below so that a program compiles and runs when I type `M-x smart-compile RET` followed by a `RET`.

```
(defcustom smart-compile-alist '(
  ;; g++-3 is used instead of g++ as the latter does not
  ;; work in Windows. Also '&& %n' is added to run the
  ;; compiled object if the compilation is successful
  ("\\.[Cc]+[Pp]*\\'" . "g++-3 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Werror 
  -Wreturn-type %f -lm -o %n && %n")
  ..
```

To give an example, for a program sqrt.cpp, smart-compile auto generates following compile command:

```
g++-3 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wreturn-type sqrt.cpp -lm -o sqrt && sqrt
```

This works as long as my .cpp does not have any `cin` statement.  For codes with `cin` statements, the console window shows the point where the user is supposed to input data. But I am unable to input anything and the Compilations status stays stuck at running.

In order to make the codes with user input work, I have to remove the `&& FILENAME` part and then manually run `./FILENAME` in emacs' `eshell`.

I am running emacs 24.3 in Windows. I have Cygwin installed and its bin added to the Windows environment variable Path (that's why g++-3 compilation works).

I would appreciate if someone could guide me how to save-compile-run user input required .cpp programs in emacs using a single command. Or at least how do I need to modify the above g++-3 command to make compile+run work for user input programs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is programmable, so if something requires two steps, you can write a command that combines them. The simples code would look like this:

```
(defun save-compile-execute ()
  (interactive)
  (smart-compile 1)                          ; step 1: compile
  (let ((exe (smart-compile-string "%n")))   ; step 2: run in *eshell*
    (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert exe)
      (eshell-send-input))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*eshell*")))
```

The above code is simple, but it has one flaw: it doesn't wait for the compilation to finish. Since `smart-compile` doesn't support a flag for synchronous compilation, this must be achieved by temporarily hooking into the `compilation-finish-functions`, which makes the code more complex:

```
(require 'cl)  ; for lexical-let

(defun do-execute (exe)
  (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert exe)
    (eshell-send-input))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*eshell*"))

(defun save-compile-execute ()
  (interactive)
  (lexical-let ((exe (smart-compile-string "./%n"))
                finish-callback)
    ;; when compilation is done, execute the program
    ;; and remove the callback from
    ;; compilation-finish-functions
    (setq finish-callback
          (lambda (buf msg)
            (do-execute exe)
            (setq compilation-finish-functions
                  (delq finish-callback compilation-finish-functions))))
    (push finish-callback compilation-finish-functions))
  (smart-compile 1))
```

The command can be run with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `save-compile-execute` <kbd>RET</kbd> or by binding it to a key.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I used your suggested function as posted but it didn't work for me. I am getting an error `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`.  I am not familiar with the Emacs Lisp syntax so I will try to understand the issue myself and if that error looks familiar to you, please update what could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried it. It almost works. The only problem now is that the `(insert exe)` portion runs instantaneously, before the compilation ends. Is there is way for the function to wait for the compilation to end? Also I had to replace `"%n"` with `"./%n"` and then it worked fine. As of now, it gives error the first time but the second time I run the 'save-compile-execute' command, it works exactly as intended as the .exe was generated the last time.

Comment: Update: I don't know how to wait for the compile to finish. But for the small codes I am practicing, 3 seconds is more than enough. So adding `(sit-for 3)` line after `(smart-compile 1)` works just fine :)

Comment: One last request please.. That will make this a perfect solution. I tried various things but am unable to make eshell the active buffer. Once I am able to do that, I think using `(end-of-buffer)` would work, right? After running save-compile-execute, it would be cool if I could directly start entering the input data without switching to eshell and scrolling to the bottom of it.

Comment: **Update** Got it, using `(switch-to-buffer-other-window "*eshell*")`.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time answering my requests. I am using your exact code snippet + `(end-of-buffer)` added to the end of `do-execute` function. As of now I don't understand the whole code completely, but it works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Oh, the code works but it gives an error: `error in process sentinel: Symbol's value as variable is void: callback`. The error appears whether or not I append `do-execute` with `(end-of-buffer)`.